# Error handling with probable missing variable

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a long chain of calcul with variables like the following one:

```
balance = (A + B + C) - (D - E) - F - G + H - I
```

Among these variables, there may be one variables ( not always the same) which impact the overall calculation by throwing an error.

The way I have though about to solve that is to use exceptions handling statement like:

```
try:
   balance = (A + B + C) - (D - E) - F - G + H - I
   except Exception as (e):
      print(e)
      pass
```

The problem is that that I still want to have the remaining of the formula as an output.
For example:

if B throw an error, the output would be:

```
balance = (A + C) - (D - E) - F - G + H - I
```

if E throw an error, the output would be:

```
balance = (A + C) - (D) - F - G + H - I
```

Is there a way to that without writing the `try` method as many times as the number of variable s? Any contribution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but it's a bit hard coded but it's the best that I could find in a very short time, if I'll find something better I will update the answer. So the solution is this:

```
balance = 0 # your initial balance
operations = 7 # number of operations - 1

# Your variables
A = 2
B = 3
I = 1

# a for so you can check all the letterals in your operation
# I forgot to mention that I forgot to put the ifs for A and B, sorry

for i in range(0, operations):
    try:
        balance = (A + B + C) - (D - E) - F - G + H - I
    except Exception as e:
        # this works as a case and switch, but it's made with ifs
        if str(e)[6] == 'C':
            C = 0
        if str(e)[6] == 'D':
            D = 0
        if str(e)[6] == 'E':
            E = 0
        if str(e)[6] == 'F':
            F = 0
        if str(e)[6] == 'G':
            G = 0
        if str(e)[6] == 'H':
            H = 0
        if str(e)[6] == 'I':
            I = 0
        print(e, "->", str(e)[6], "= 0")
print(balance)
```

Sorry if it's not a very detailed answer but it's my first post on StackOverflow. :)

EDIT: so I found a very nice way of solving this without that many ifs, the question about 'Is it possible without using try/exception?' I think the answer is no, because it's the only way of finding out that there is actually an error. This is the solution:

```
import re # import regular expression module

balance = 0 # your initial balance
number_operations = 7 # number of operations - 1

# your variables
A = 2
B = 3
H = 1

# this is the pattern to find the variable later when the Exception is called
# error = name 'variable' is not defined
# with this pattern you can get whatever variable is not defined in the balance formula
pattern = r"'.+'"

# a for so you can check all the letterals in your operation
for i in range(0, number_operations):
    try:
        balance = (A + B + C) - (D - E) - F - G + H - I_like_turtles
    except Exception as error:
        letter = re.search(pattern, str(error)) # gives a re object that contains 'C' (in case of undefined C)
        letter = letter.group(0)[1:-1] # gives the string 'C' that we cut so we get just C
        exec("%s = %d" % (letter, 0)) # dinamically creates a variable so we can have C = 0
        print(error, "->", letter, "= 0")
print("C =", C)
print("D =", D)
print("I like turtles =", I_like_turtles)
print(balance)
```

That last variable was just to test that with this method you can get whatever variable you need. I hope this solved your problem. :D